# Find a basis for $\ U \cap W $

Tags: linear-algebra

> Two subspaces  $\ W = \{ 1+ x + x^3 , -2x+x^2+x^3 , 3+ x + x^2 + 4x ^ 3\} $ and $\ U = \{ a+bx-bx^2+2ax^3 \mid a,b \in \mathbb R \} $

so $\ W = \{ w_1 = (1,1,0,1), w_2 = (0,-2,1,1), w_3 = (3,1,1,4) \} , \\ U = \{ u_1 = (1,0,0,2), u_2 = (0,-1,1,0) \}  $

and I need to find basis for $\ U \cap W $ so if $\ v \in U \cap W $ this means $\ 0 = \alpha_1 w_1 + \alpha_2 w_2 + \alpha_3 w _3 - \alpha_4 u_1 - \alpha_5u_2$

so I should just rank it in matrix and  so
$\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 2 & 0 & - 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $

so it means $\alpha_1 = \alpha_3 = \alpha_4 $ and $\ \alpha_2 = - \alpha_3 $ so it means any $\ v \in U \cap W $ is $\ v= \alpha_1u_1 -\alpha_1u_2 $ or $\ v = \alpha_3w_3 - \alpha_3 w_4  $

and how do I show by which vectors the space $\ U \cap W $ is spanned??

Comment: A vector space can have more than one basis that can be used to span the whole space...assuming your calculations are correct either is the correct answer.

Comment: What do you denote $w_4$?

Answer (score 0):

We have $3w_1+w_2 = w_3$ so the basis for $W$ is actually $\{w_1, w_2\}$.

On the other hand, check that $\{w_1, w_2, u_1\}$ is linearly independent while

$$u_2 = w_1 + w_2 - u_1$$

This implies that $\dim (W + U) = 3$ so

$$\dim (W \cap U) = \dim W + \dim U - \dim (W + U) = 2 + 2 - 3 = 1$$

Finally notice that $$W \ni w_1 + w_2 = u_1 + u_2 \in U$$

so $\{w_1 + w_2\} = \{(1,-1,1,2)\}$ is a basis for $W\cap U$.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the *augmented matrix* with columns $w_1,w_2,w_3$ and a generic vector in $U$ to determine the compatibility conditions for this generic vector to be in $W$:
\begin{align}
\left[\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c<{\mkern-20mu}}
1 & 0 & 3 & a \\
1 & -2& 1 & b \\
0 & 1& 1 & -b\\
1 & 1 & 4 & 2a
\end{array}\!
\right] &\rightsquigarrow
\left[\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c<{\mkern-20mu}}
1 & 0 & 3 & a \\
0 & -2 & -2 & b-a \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -b\\
0 & 1 & 1 & a
\end{array}\!
\right] \rightsquigarrow
\left[\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c<{\mkern-20mu}}
1 & 0 & 3 & a \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{a-b}2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & -b\\
0 & 1 & 1 & a
\end{array}\!
\right] \rightsquigarrow 
\left[\!
\begin{array}{ccc|c<{\mkern-20mu}}
1 & 0 & 3 & a \\
0 & 1 & 1 & \frac{a-b}2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{a+b}2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{a+b}2
\end{array}\!
\right]
\end{align}
so the compatibility condition is $\color{red}{b=-a}$, and a vector in $U\cap W$ can be written as
$$u=a-ax+ax^2+2ax^3=a(\underbrace{1-x+x^2+2x^3}_{\text{basis of }\:U\cap W})$$